# AssertionError in adding lyr file

Tags: arcpy, layers, assertionerror

This is only part of a bigger code block that I'm building.

The goal of these lines is to import a new layer, and select one feature from the feature class(TOWNSSURVEY_POLYM). The code imports the .shp as a layer feature successfully, however, it throws an error after running (regardless of whether or not the I included the bit about selectLayerByAttribute_management() ).

Here's the error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 48, in AddLayer
    assert isinstance(data_frame, DataFrame)
AssertionError
```

If I'm not mistaken, it seems to me as though the problem has to do with the my dataframe not being accepted as a string. Here's my code block.

I am still new to ArcPy.

```
from arcpy import mapping

## setting variables to parameters

map = mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mapping.ListDataFrames(map)[0].name = "Data Frame"
data = 'C:\Users\GIS\FilePath\TOWNSSURVEY_POLYM'

## adding the new layer as a '.lyr' file, as ArcMap won't allow you to directly import '.shp' files

lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(data)

#mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "AUTO_ARRANGE"), NEW_SELECTION, ' [TOWN] = "ASHBY" ' )




arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = mapping.ListDataFrames(map)[0].name = "Data Frame"
```

This is wrong.  Take a look at [ListDataFrames ArcGIS Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listdataframes.htm).  You should specify the name of your data frame in `ListDataFrames()` using the wildcard parameter.

```
df = mapping.ListDataFrames(map, "Data Frame")[0]
```

Additionally, if this is the only dataframe in your MXD, you could just specify the dataframe using

```
df = map.activedataframe
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I needed. The reason I used that line in particular was because [MapDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm) >Code Samples>MapDocuments Example 2. It seems as though the example given renames or assigns a name to an existing data frame. But 'activeDataFrame' seems much more efficient.  Thanks!

Comment: @mgallotta that code sample will be to rename it, not to specify one by name for your `df` variable.